# How to use split in C# in this scenario

Tags: c#, string, split

I am trying to split a string by following approach:

```
string strValue = myDropdownList.SelectedValue.ToString();

//Split the dropdown selected value and assign to Name and Number
string[] strArray = strValue.Split('-');

string Name = strArray[0].Trim();
string Number = strArray.Trim();
```

The above approach worked fine so far.

My dropdown has values like this "Name - Number".

For ex: "Jennifer Austin - 546465".

So I used get the name and number into respective string fields.

But right now I see the dropdown has a few values like the following:

```
"Tenneson Jeff - LLC - 56454564"
"Barmer Auto-VH, LLC - 6545646"
```

So with the above list items in my dropdown, if I split with my regular approach, I get bad values into my name and number string fields.

How do I approach to get the exact name and number into respective string fields by splitting the dropdown list items.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You have two dashes in your examples.  Do you want to split on the last dash?

Comment: have you tried `strValue.Split(new []{" - "});`

Comment: Is the second value always a number / is it always after the last slash? If either of those is true, you can use a regex

Comment: Use `LastIndexOf()`.  See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21733934/102937) for an example.

Comment: Since there are only two fields, and you know the precise format of the 2nd field, I suggest a regular expression in this case to match on the delimiter and 2nd field.

Comment: You should be able to store and object ion the control and access a Name versus Value members without commingling data into a string

Comment: @santosh this should work: 
 var name = input.Substring(0, input.LastIndexOf('-')).Trim();
 var number = input.Substring(input.LastIndexOf('-')+1).Trim();

Comment: @HanjunChen its giving me an error. Cannot convert from string[] to char

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regex such as this:

```
var regex = new System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex(@"^\s*(?<name>.*?)\s*-\s*(?<no>\d+)\s*$", RegexOptions.Compiled);

var value = "Tenneson Jeff - LLC - 56454564";
var matches = regex.Matches(value);
var name = matches?[0]?.Groups["name"]?.Value;
var number = matches?[0]?.Groups["no"]?.Value;
Console.WriteLine(name);
Console.WriteLine(number);
```

Explanation of regex and examples here: https://regex101.com/r/CEe8rU/3

Documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex?view=netframework-4.7.2